# C++ 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded

Tags: visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

i am trying to launch GUI app with console for debugging, but  it keeps crashing  :

```
    #include "main_form.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>



using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void WinMain()
{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    AgeOfExpress::main_form form;

}
```

error : 'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded
I am  newbie in c++ , can anyone help me  ? 
P.S. : i am using visual studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. You need to edit subsystem :)